# Can we check "AND" condition inside when(x)

Tags: android, kotlin

In [Kotlin refenrence](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html), it is written as multiple conditions can be matched using comma (,) inside a `when` control flow. For example-

```
when (x) {
    0, 1 -> print("x == 0 or x == 1")
    else -> print("otherwise")
}
```

Here, in the first condition comma works like an OR operator.
Is there any way to write an expression to match AND condition inside `when`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Although the syntax is somewhat different:

```
when {
    x % 5 == 0 && x % 3 == 0 -> println("foobar")
    x % 5 == 0 -> println("bar")
    x % 3 == 0 -> println("foo")
}
```